# Winforms usercontrol phenomenon : suddenly all items are away!

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a **winform usercontrol** with several items (textboxes, buttons,...). Now I am confronted with **phenomenon**, that all items are suddenly away  (in the **VS 2010** designer view / document outline), although in the control designer file (**designer.cs**) the textboxes, buttons,... are still defined. There is also no compilation error. When I run the application, the items are still missing! I have already restarted VS!
Does anybody know, what the reason for this is?

Comment: Visual Studio needs some coffee :).. What happens when you run program? Still controls missing on runtime?

Comment: yes, they are missing also on runtime

Comment: So, try to add a control, and run project. And let us know if newly added control will dissappear like old ones.

Comment: Did you hit Ctrl+A+Delete instead of Ctrl+Alt+Delete? ;)

Comment: I added a button. It is seen in the designer and during runtime!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the InitializeComponent method do all the controls get added to the form via this.Controls.Add... statements?

I know this happened with VS2003 a lot that these code lines would disappear. I suspect that this is the problem

Comment: thank you for this hint. All "this.Controls.Add(..)" has been disappeared/deleted!!

Comment: Haha, wow. What a terrible bug! So it still happens in VS 2010, huh? Not too encouraging...

Answer (score 2):

1. Did you possibly remove the call to `InitializeComponent` from your control's constructor by accident?
2. Does the **name** of the `partial class` in your .designer.cs file match that of your "main" control file?
3. Try running your application through VS's debugger. Put a breakpoint at `InitializeComponent` and step through all the code responsible for creating and placing all the controls in your user control. Maybe you will happen upon an explanation this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your Visual Studio, and the do a Rebuild Solution.