# Retrieve Visibility Of Design Controls On The Win Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have design winform with various controls on it like textbox/ComboBox and Panels  on some days ago but now if I am trying to run the forms the forms is visible but the controls which are designed on it is not visible. I don’t know what is the reason or some mistake made by me in past with it. But the reality is that I am unable to retrieve the controls on the forms.

**Form11.cs**  (code design ) file is available as well as **form11Designer.cs** file is also there in well coded format.

Don’t know where is the mistake and how to retrieve all the controls which I have designed on it?

Comment: In the designer the controls are visible?

Comment: You check out a previous version of the files from your source control system? Don't have one? Get one now. It saves your from those things that just "happen" to your code.

Comment: You need to look in those files for any trace of your controls, if they are not there they are gone. If they are there, but does not show up as expected you need to post your code here, since we don't have crystal balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this post: [Winforms usercontrol phenomenon : suddenly all items are away!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933979/winforms-usercontrol-phenomenon-suddenly-all-items-are-away/4934187#4934187)

Answer (score 0):

In the Visual Studio form designer, open the "Properties" view. At the top of it, there will be a drop-down list box of all the controls on the form. You should be able to find and select your control from that box.  When a control is selected from that list box, it is also 'selected' in the form designer itself, so should get the selection rectangle around it. Your control might just be hiding behind another control...